# Meaning of "in the same way as ~" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "in the same way as ~" in the following sentences,

> Internal symmetries relate similar types of particles. For example,
> isospin relates protons and neutrons, which have the same spin, and
> about the same mass, but different charge. The proton and neutron form
> a doublet that transform into each other, **in the same way as** the 2
> spin states of a spin 1/2 particle, hence the name "isospin".

? (Source: [http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/particle.html](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Esiegel/particle.html))

Does "~in the same way as the 2 spin states" mean "The proton and neutron form a doublet that transform into each other. Each other in the same way is the 2 spin states of a spin 1/2 particle" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about 1/2 particles, but I would interpret that sentence to mean:

> The proton and neutron form a doublet that transform into each other, in the same way as the 2 spin states of a spin 1/2 particle [transform into each other], hence the name "isospin".